# How to make QTabWidget look transparent?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to make a simple GUI desktop application using python.

I've made a simple window with a background image, and I added a tab-widget on the right corner. It worked properly. But the tab-bar and tab contents area are white.

What I want is that the tab-widget's background shows it's parent window's background image (which means it's transparent). But I don't know how to do it.

Here is my working environment, code and screen shot:

**Working environment**:

- Windows 7
- Python 3.4
- PyQt5 5.5

**Source code**:

```
# coding: utf-8

# There are some unnecessary module. 

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPalette, QBrush, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        tab1 = QWidget()
        tab2 = QWidget()

        vbox1 = self.makeTab1()
        vbox2 = self.makeTab2()

        tab1.setLayout(vbox1)
        tab2.setLayout(vbox2)

        tabs = QTabWidget()
        tabs.addTab(tab1, "firstTab")
        tabs.addTab(tab2, "secondTab")

        picLabel = QLabel(self)
        picFile = 'background_img.jpg'
        pixmap = QPixmap(picFile)
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background, QBrush(pixmap))

        hboxEX = QHBoxLayout()
        hboxEX.addStretch(2)
        hboxEX.addWidget(tabs)
        hboxEX.setStretchFactor(tabs, 1)

        vboxEX = QVBoxLayout()
        vboxEX.addStretch(1)
        vboxEX.addLayout(hboxEX)
        vboxEX.setStretchFactor(hboxEX, 1)

        self.setLayout(vboxEX)

        self.setPalette(palette)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        self.show()

    def makeTab1(self):
        lbl1 = QLabel(self)
        lbl2 = QLabel(self)
        lbl3 = QLabel(self)

        lbl1.setText("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>")
        lbl2.setText("<a href=\"https://www.wikipedia.org/\">WikiPedia</a>")
        lbl3.setText("<a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com\">StackOverflow</a>")

        lbl1.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        lbl2.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        lbl3.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        vbox1 = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox1.addWidget(lbl1)
        vbox1.addWidget(lbl2)
        vbox1.addWidget(lbl3)

        return vbox1

    def makeTab2(self):
        lbl4 = QLabel(self)
        lbl5 = QLabel(self)
        lbl6 = QLabel(self)

        lbl4.setText("<a href=\"https://www.python.org/\">Python</a>")
        lbl5.setText("<a href=\"https://www.centos.org/\">CentOS</a>")
        lbl6.setText("<a href=\"https://mariadb.org/\">MariaDB</a>")

        lbl4.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        lbl5.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        lbl6.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        vbox2 = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox2.addWidget(lbl4)
        vbox2.addWidget(lbl5)
        vbox2.addWidget(lbl6)

        return vbox2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Screen shot**:

[image: screenshot]

What I tried:

I added these codes and it changed the tab's color. But it didn't make the tab area look transparent:

```
    tabPalette = QPalette()
    tabPalette.setColor(QPalette.Background, QColor("cyan"))
    tab1.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    tab1.setPalette(tabPalette)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a Windows problem. You might want to try to switch your application to a different style.

See this page of PyQt reference http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstyle.html

some sample code:

```
def changeStyle(self, styleName):
    QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create(styleName))
    self.changePalette()
```

call it with:

```
changeStyle("plastique")
```

Comment: While the link in the answer might solve the problem. You should consider adding some code in this answer.

Comment: Thank you Kevin Eaverquepedo. I am studying how to adopt your answer to my code. Your answer shows me a way to solve. Thank you again.

Comment: Let me know if you're able to @passion053. I am still not able to do it.